# How to calculate $R^2$ in GLMMTMB?

Tags: glmm

How to calculate R&2  in GLMMTMB?   I

```
glmmTMB(formula = ladybettles ~ Pesticide_flower + SHDI + (1 | 
SITE) + orchard + cotton + maize + buildings + semi_habitats + 
other_crop + tree + water, data = dat, family = nbinom2(link = "log"), 
ziformula = ~0, dispformula = ~1)
```

This is my model . 
How to caculate  R^2. THanks in advance.

Comment: You can try the rsq package.

Comment: thank you very much